# Ruby lang - How to check string exists in @name attribute of objects in Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, object

Got an array of objects with attribute - @name. 
Trying to check, if exact string exists as @name attribute of that objects. Seems my solution does not work for this.

tried all array methods and enumerators, but it does not do correct comparison

```
class StObjName
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
      @name = name
  end
end

@st_names = []
@st_names << StObjName.new("Chicago") # just to have something in array


if @st_names.each{|obj| obj.name == "LA" }
    puts "We already have name -> LA!"
else
    @st_names << StObjName.new("LA")
    puts "new name #{@st_names.last.name} added!"
end

# Output: => We already have name -> LA!
```

`if` - must go through each object in `@st_names` array and output `"We already have name -> LA!"` in case any name in any object of array is equal to string `"LA"`.

`else` - must add into array new object named `"LA"` in case previous if is not true

Answer (score 2):

`each` returns the enumerable back, which is always truthy. What you need is [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
if @st_names.any? { |obj| obj.name == "LA" }
```